# Jacobi identity for the bracket in action Lie algebroid

Tags: lie-algebroids

I am trying to verify that the bracket in the definition of action Lie algebroid satisfies the Jaboci Identity.

Let $X \to X^\dagger$ be an action of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ on a manifold $M$, i.e., for all $X \in \mathfrak{g},~ X^\dagger$ is a vector field on $M$, and $X \mapsto X^\dagger$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, and preserves bracket; $[X,Y]^\dagger = [X^\dagger, Y^\dagger]$ for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Extend the dagger notation to maps $V: M \to \mathfrak{g}$ so that $V^\dagger$ is the vector field defined as $V^\dagger(m):= V(m)^\dagger (m)$ on $M$.

Then the trivial vector bundle $M \times \mathfrak{g}$ on $M$ acquires a Lie algebroid structure with the anchor map $a:M \times \mathfrak{g} \to TM$ defined by $a(m,X) := X^\dagger (m)$ and the bracket $$[V,W] := V^\dagger(W) - W^\dagger(V) + [V,W]^{\bullet}$$ where $V^\dagger(W)$ is the Lie derivative of $W$ with respect to $V^\dagger$ of the vector valued function $W$, and $[V,W]^{\bullet}$ is the pointwise bracket of maps into $\mathfrak{g}$.

---

I am unable to show that the bracket defined above satisfies the Jacobi Identity:

Expanding the terms in the Jacobi Identity we get the following:

$$
[[U,V],W] = (U\dagger(V))^\dagger(W) - W^\dagger(U^\dagger(V)) + [U^\dagger(V),W]^\bullet \\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
-(V^\dagger(U))^\dagger(W) + W^\dagger(V^\dagger(U)) - [V^\dagger(U),W]^\bullet 
\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ ([U,V]^\bullet)^\dagger(W) - W^\dagger([U,V]^\bullet) + [[U,V]^\bullet,W]^\bullet
$$

$$
[[V,W],U]= (V^\dagger(W))^\dagger(U) - U^\dagger(V^\dagger(W)) + [V^\dagger(W),U]^\bullet 
\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
- (W^\dagger(V))^\dagger(U) + U^\dagger(W^\dagger(V)) - [W^\dagger(V),U]^\bullet
\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ ([V,W]^\bullet)^\dagger - U^\dagger([V,W]^\bullet) + [[V,W]^\bullet,U]^\bullet 
$$

$$
[[W,U],V]= (W^\dagger(U))^\dagger(V) - V^\dagger(W^\dagger(U)) + [W^\dagger(U),V]^\bullet
\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-(U^\dagger(W))^\dagger(V) + V^\dagger(U^\dagger(W)) - [U^\dagger(W),V]^\bullet
\\~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ ([W,U]^\bullet)^\dagger (V) - V^\dagger([W,U]^\bullet) + [[W,U]^\bullet,V]^\bullet
$$

After adding the above three terms and canceling all the possible terms I have got:

$$[[U,V],W] + [[V,W],U] + [[W,U],V] = $$
$$
\Big((U^\dagger(V))^\dagger(W) - (V^\dagger(U))^\dagger(W)\Big) + \Big((V^\dagger(W))^\dagger(U) - (W^\dagger(V))^\dagger(U)\Big) + \Big((W^\dagger(U))^\dagger(V) - (W^\dagger(V))^\dagger(U)\Big)
\\
+
\\
\Big([U^\dagger(V),W]^\bullet - [V^\dagger(U),W]^\bullet - W^\dagger([U,V]^\bullet)\Big) +
\Big([V^\dagger(W),U]^\bullet - [W^\dagger(V),U]^\bullet - U^\dagger([V,W]^\bullet)\Big) +
\Big([W^\dagger(U),V]^\bullet - [U^\dagger(W),V]^\bullet - V^\dagger([W,U]^\bullet)\Big)
$$
I cannot find a way to cancel out these terms. Maybe I think there are some properties of the Lie derivative that I will have to use. Can anyone please help me with these?

Comment: are you still looking for help?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Thank you for replying. Yes. I am still looking for help. You are from IISER Pune, right? I tried contacting you through email as well.

Comment: Sorry. Did not see the message. I have not recieved any email, I checked spam also. Please consider sending to praphullakoushik16@gmail.com the same email that I mentioned in my webpage.